# F# InitInfinite(Async) functions in C# without disabling ReSharper warnings

Tags: c#

When coding in C# I often miss some functions from the F# world.

One of them is [`Seq.initInfinite`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L477), others are its counterparts with the `AsyncSeq` library:

- [`AsyncSeq.initInfiniteAsync`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/blob/28fe3c3ce9a8adbe3c914852b70f8fef120ec04b/src/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/AsyncSeq.fs#L933)
- [`AsyncSeq.initInfinite`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/blob/28fe3c3ce9a8adbe3c914852b70f8fef120ec04b/src/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/AsyncSeq.fs#L950)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public static class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> InitInfinite<T>(Func<T> itemFactory)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return itemFactory();
        }
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorNeverReturns
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> InitInfinite<T>(Func<BigInteger, T> itemFactory)
    {
        var index = BigInteger.Zero;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return itemFactory(index);
            index++;
        }
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorNeverReturns
    }
}
public static class AsyncEnumerable
{
#pragma warning disable 1998
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> InitInfinite<T>(Func<T> itemFactory)
#pragma warning restore 1998
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return itemFactory();
        }
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorNeverReturns
    }
#pragma warning disable 1998
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> InitInfinite<T>(Func<BigInteger, T> itemFactory)
#pragma warning restore 1998
    {
        var index = BigInteger.Zero;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return itemFactory(index);
            index++;
        }
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorNeverReturns
    }
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> InitInfiniteAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> asyncItemFactory)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return await asyncItemFactory();
        }
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorNeverReturns
    }
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> InitInfiniteAsync<T>(Func<BigInteger, Task<T>> asyncItemFactory)
    {
        var index = BigInteger.Zero;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return await asyncItemFactory(index);
            index++;
        }
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorNeverReturns
    }
}
```

My code is working as expected, like in the example below:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var asyncResultWithIntegers = await AsyncEnumerable
            .InitInfiniteAsync(i => Task.FromResult(i))
            .Take(4)
            .ToArrayAsync();

        var asyncResultWithoutIntegers = await AsyncEnumerable
            .InitInfiniteAsync(() => Task.FromResult("Hi there!"))
            .Take(4)
            .ToArrayAsync();

        var resultWithIntegers = await AsyncEnumerable
            .InitInfinite(i => i)
            .Take(4)
            .ToArrayAsync();

        var resultWithoutIntegers = await AsyncEnumerable
            .InitInfinite(() => "Hi there!")
            .Take(4)
            .ToArrayAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to implement those. In particular, is there a way to implement those methods without disabling the ReSharper warnings?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! It seems like someone voted to close this question because it does not work. Does your code currently work as intended? If yes, please state so in the question (to avoid confusion). You might also want to add an example of how this code is being used.

Comment: @Graipher thanks your message
"It seems like someone voted to close this question because it does not work" I kinda resent when people are doing that without giving any sort of guidance (I know it's not a requirement) but afaik no explicit reason was given when the downvote happened.

"Does your code currently work as intended?"
Yes, it does

Comment: Well, yeah, it kinda sucks sometimes. I agree that if voting to close because the code does not work this should be worth a comment. But I also have to admit that I don't do it everytime as well... But if it is because of a bug I try to always comment, because otherwise the other people in the queue have no guidance about what is wrong. Let alone the OP not knowing what they should fix, if anything, either, as you have experienced now.

Comment: Agreed, I'm adding a few examples, and my code should be all good.

Comment: What's with the magic numbers? The examples show your code in action, which is good, but for those of us not fluent in F#, what really prompted you to write this?

Comment: If you're talking about the pragma number: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243975/suppress-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lacks-await

Ah... don't tell me that =|

Comment: Do you actually need infinity results? Or do you always expect to Take a certain amount? If it's the latter, you could just use [Enumerable.Repeat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=netframework-4.8) or [Enumerable.Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @devNull I'll answer you tonight. But yes I possibly need an infinity of results (can depend on some parameters, say user input)